# SHA-256 hashing function in Java ME/J2ME

Tags: java-me, hmac, sha256

I've posted this question on the Nokia Developer forums so please bear with me.

I'm writing an app which needs to find the SHA-256 hash of a URL keyed with a unique value – i.e. `hmac('sha256', '27/3', '9EWVFmHpHN6n2YKW9QtvUqX3xbsFQUBovlrFddqnF7fpcSDA2q')`. What would be the best way to do this in Java ME/J2ME?

I've found many examples using the `Mac` class but this isn't supported in Java ME/J2ME.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get things working, the solution is as follows:

```
Digest  digest = new SHA256Digest();
HMac hmac = new HMac(digest);
hmac.init(new KeyParameter(appKeyHere));
hmac.update(requestURI, 0, lenOfReqURI);
byte[]  resBuf = new byte[digest.getDigestSize()];
hmac.doFinal(resBuf, 0);
String  resStr = new String(Hex.encode(resBuf)); // Contains final usable value
```

Comment: hmac.doFinal(resbuf, 0); In this line is the "resbuf" and " resBuf" in line byte[]  resBuf = new byte[digest.getDigestSize()] are same?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

[BouncyCastle's latest J2ME compatible release (the lightweight API)](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) contains among other things an SHA256 implementation - `org.bouncycastle.crypto.digests.SHA256Digest` - that should work for you.

Comment: Many thanks. Do you perhaps have a usage example? I find the BC API documentation confusing at the best of times.

Comment: @Bataleon There are some examples from the tests in the BouncyCastle code [in the Google cache here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:kqNEdaKuo9YJ:massapi.com/class/org/bouncycastle/crypto/digests/SHA256Digest.java.html+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=se) that should help. The original site [here](http://massapi.com/class/org/bouncycastle/crypto/digests/SHA256Digest.java.html) is currently unreachable for me.