# I'm creating a j2me app to generate one time password in netbeans 7.3.i need to do compute sha-256 hash on a string

Tags: java-me, sha256

```
otp=otp.concat(imei).concat(imsi).concat(username).concat(password).concat(hr).concat(min).concat(day).concat(year).concat(month).concat(dday);
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            md.update(otp.getBytes(),0,otp.getBytes().length);
            byte byteData[]=null;
            md.digest(byteData,0,32);
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int  j= 0; j < byteData.length; j++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[j] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
            }
```

This code works in a java pgm but when i run this in the emulator,i get this exception:

```
The application has unexpectedly quit. Contact the application provider to resolve the issue.
SHA-256
```

Pls.help me

Comment: I've noticed whenever a JavaME encryption question pops up, that people tend to recommend Bouncy Castle. So this thread may be useful to you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568728/sha-256-hashing-function-in-java-me-j2me

Comment: I treid that already but it isn't working...is there any way to compute sha256 other than Bouncy Castle?