# How to convert String to SHA-256 hash in J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me, cryptography, sha256

The application I'm working on requires a String to be converted to a SHA-256 hash, but since it's J2ME I don't have access to MessageDigest full functionality.

I tried BouncyCastle library but when I compare the resulting hash with the result from an online page, the values are different.

Another way for me to know the hash wasn't created right is to send it to my server in a HTTP request, if I can login then the hash was created correctly, else it was malformed.

I've been told that I should implement my own SHA-256 enconding but so far I haven't found examples or the algorithm itself, only the pseudocode from the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Pseudocode) and worse I don't have experience in cryptography at all.

Do I have to create my own implementation? or is there still chance for me to avoid this and use a different library?

Here is the current piece of code I tried with BouncyCastle:

```
            String[] stringArray = (String[]) dotREZApi.getCurrentRequest().getResponseHeaders().get("X-Session-Id");
            String tmpSessionId = stringArray[0];

            byte[] input = null;
            try {
                input = new String("X-Session-Sig" + tmpSessionId + "test").getBytes("UTF-8"); // String that will be converted
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("Unsupported encoding exception");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // trying to create a key, i don't know if this is right I just did this because I needed a key             
            byte[] key = new byte[4];
            int tmpInt = new Random().nextInt();
            key[0] = (byte)(tmpInt >> 24);
            key[1] = (byte)(tmpInt >> 16);
            key[2] = (byte)(tmpInt >> 8);
            key[3] = (byte)(tmpInt);


            Digest digest = new SHA256Digest();
            HMac hmac = new HMac(digest);

            hmac.init(new KeyParameter(key)); // maybe this is the problem? the documentaiton never states where do I get this key or how to generate it
            hmac.update(input, 0, input.length);
            byte[] output = new byte[digest.getDigestSize()];
            hmac.doFinal(output, 0);
            dotREZApi.setSessionSig(new String(Hex.encode(output)));
```

The result I get from this I compare to the one I get from this [site](http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator), but I don't get match.

The line `input = new String("X-Session-Sig" + tmpSessionId + "test").getBytes("UTF-8");` is where I construct the string and then convert it to byte[] to convert to SHA-256 hash, where tmpSessionId is a value I get from a HTTP request. The resulting hash will be sent in future requests.

Comment: You mean BouncyCastle. How are you hashing the string? Can you show us some code? You shouldn't have to re-implement SHA-256.

Comment: check my edited answer, I put some code but to be honest I was going to give up on bouncy castle since I haven't been able to get a correct result.

is my implementation right?

Comment: I guess my problem is in the key generation, but I haven't found documentation that explains what is this key or how to generate it. I found a generic way to create a random key and that's what i used.

Comment: Why not try Apache Commons Codec?

Comment: Is it supported by J2ME for Nokia Asha development? If it is then, is the jar too big? Asha apps have a small size limit which restricts the libraries I can use.

Comment: Okay, so despite your original question, you aren't using SHA-256, but rather HMAC-SHA-256. You'll get a different output for any combination of key and input, so you have to find out what key the server uses.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SHA-256 hashing function in Java ME/J2ME](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568728/sha-256-hashing-function-in-java-me-j2me)

Comment: it is not since I'm stating that BouncyCastle didn't work for me at all

Comment: can someone unmark this question as duplicate, it is not a duplicate, both questions have a different problem context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I didn't use BouncyCastle.

I ended up using MessageDigest from J2ME, and while it doesn't have the same methods available, I could get it to work:

```
    byte[] input = null;
    try {
        input = new String("X-Session-Id" + tmpSessionId + "test").getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Unsupported encoding exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    MessageDigest messageDigest;
    byte[] output = new byte[32]; // since SHA256 hash is 256 bits = 32 bytes
    try {
        messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        messageDigest.update(input, 0, input.length);
        messageDigest.digest(output, 0, 32); // same
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DigestException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I hope this alternative to BouncyCastle works for others too.

If someone could unmark this question as a duplicated since my problem was with BouncyCastle and was looking for an alternative to it since BouncyCastle is what most pages recommend.